# selection update on model sorting/re-ordering with Qt

Tags: c++, qt, qabstractitemmodel

I'm trying do redefine a proxy model that can do sorting and re-ordering (the user can order each row as he wants).

As far as I'm aware, there's nothing straight out of the box in Qt to do that, so I'm desperately trying to make my own proxy model, inheriting QAbstractProxyModel.

I based most of what I did on the actual code of QSortFilterProxyModel, but I'm still missing some features.

Most important to me is the selection after sorting/reordering.

If I use a QSortFilterProxyModel, the selection on my table view follows the sort (ie, the same item is selected), but if I use my model, it does not (the same line stays selected).

Anyone has any idea how this behavior is done with QSortFilterModel? does it have anything to do with these weird persistent indexes I don't really understand?

Comment: This thread can help you understand persistent index : http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/35208-how-does-QPersistentModelIndex-quot-work-quot

Comment: Thanks but I'm still not sure if it's because of them that the view manages to update its selection after a sort, any confirmation on that? Any other possible lead?

Comment: Can I ask what functionality you require that `QSortFilterProxyModel` doesn't already provide?  In all my years of Qt use I've had to extend `QSortFilterProxyModel` on occasion but I've never had to inherit from `QAbstractProxyModel` and essentially start from scratch.  Your requirements may be different of course.

Comment: Just the possibility to re-order rows, by moving them up or down, or ideally with drag and drop.

Comment: @Julien Lopez -- That should all come under the remit of [`QSortFilterProxy::lessThan`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsortfilterproxymodel.html#lessThan) which you can override.  But if you're moving rows explicitly/manually then you will almost certainly require the use of [`QPersistentModelIndex`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qpersistentmodelindex.html) in your sorting logic.